# Role Claim not working in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API after upgrading to .NET 8

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, .net-8.0

I have a `.NET 7 ASP.NET Core 7.0` `Web API` project which uses `.NET 7 ASP.NET Core 7.0` `IdentityServer4` Project. Everything is working fine.

Here is my code setup:

**IdentityServer4:**

In my `ProfileService` in `IdentityServer4` project, I'm adding a `role` `claim` as show below.

`ProfileService.cs:`

```cs
claims.Add(new Claim("role", "master"));
```

`Startup.cs:`

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

**Web API:**

I have added `Authorization` services in `Program.cs`

`Program.cs:`

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, SubjectMustMatchUserHandler>();

services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
            {
                authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
                Policies.SubjectMustMatchUser,
                policyBuilder =>
                {
                    policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new SubjectMustMatchUserRequirement());
                });

                authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(Policies.MustBeMasterUser, Policies.MustBeMasterUserPolicy());
            })
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthorityUrl");
            options.Audience = "redacted";
        });
```

`Authorization Policy:`

```cs
public static AuthorizationPolicy MustBeMasterUserPolicy()
{
    return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim("role", "master")
        .Build();
}
```

**Claims:**

[image]

Till now all is working fine.

Now I have updated my project to `.NET 8` and the `Role` `Claim` is not working as expected and my policies are failing.

When I debug, I noticed the change in the name of `role` claim key from `role` to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` as shown below

[image]

This change is making my policies to fail. I'm not able to find any docs to fix this in Migration guides. Please can you help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: see my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify what the name of your role and name claim is, using:

```
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    // ...
    opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
    opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    // ...
});
```

You might also want to disable the rename of the claims, by:

```
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    // ...
    opt.MapInboundClaims = false;
    // ...
});
```

For more details, see my blog post here:
[Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Is this something newly changes in `.NET 8`? because my code worked with `.NET 7` I'm reading and testing this. Will upvote once I complete my analysis.

Comment: I am not sure about about that.

Answer (score 1):

We already had the TokenValidationParameters set so that did not help.

It works if I use the full claim name as follows.

```
options.AddPolicy(AccountDefaults.AdminPolicy, p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim(//JwtClaimTypes.Role
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", AccountDefaults.Administrator));
```

We then realised that we can use

```
ClaimTypes.Role
```

Resulting in

```
options.AddPolicy(AccountDefaults.AdminPolicy, p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AccountDefaults.Administrator));
```